# Distribution of a slice of a line with normally distributed slope

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Give the random variable $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma)$  consider the process $Y_t = tX$ with $t \in I = [t_1,t_2]$, informally a line with a random slope.

I would like to find the distribution of the points in the process $\{Y_t\}$ that follow the constraint of being on a line, say $l = tS + b$. Informally, the distribution of the intersection of the process $\{Y_t\}$ and the line $l$.

On the picture that would be the points lying on the blue line, where the red line is the mean of the process and the gray lines mark the variance (not the standard deviation).

[image]

$\forall t \in I$ I used the fact that $E[Y_t] = tE[X]$ and $Var[Y_t] = t^2Var[X]$.

Running a quick experiment delivers the following histogram of the (x-coordinate of the) intersection points

[image]

I would assume it is some sort of skewed normal, as it looks like from the histogram, but I don't know how to derive it analytically.
Is it actually possible to derive this distribution analytically? Or, is this following a known physical process?

Comment: The distribution of $Y_t$ conditional on $Y_t = tS + b$ is just the degenerate distribution that yields only the number $tS + b$. Perhaps you mean to ask a question about the marginal distribution of $Y_T$ for some random variable $T$ on $I$.

Comment: Welcome, Francesco! Your graphs would be ***much*** improved by axis labels.

Comment: @Kodiologist I believe that here I'm looking for the distribution of $T|Y_t = TS + b$. I think that if it were $Y_t|T = t' $ as you suggest, then this would be a normal distribution $N(t'\mu,t'^2\sigma^2)$. But please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Francesco I'm not sure what you're looking for, but I agree that the unconditional distribution of $Y_t$ is normal for each $t$.

Answer (score 0):

The line $y=tX$ intersects the line $y=tS+b$ at the value $t$ satisfying
$$
tX=tS+b.
$$
Solving for $t$ gives
$$
t=\frac b{X-S}.\tag1
$$
If $S$ and $b$ are constants and $X$ has normal$(\mu,\sigma)$ distribution, then the denominator of (1) has normal$(\mu-S,\sigma)$ distribution. So if we denote by $T$ the $x$-coordinate of this point of intersection, the random variable $T:=\frac b{X-S}$  is distributed like ($b$ times) the reciprocal of a normal distribution. In terms of a standard normal $Z$ we can write
$$
T=\frac b{\sigma Z+(\mu-S)}.
$$

If unrestricted, $T$ will take both positive and negative values. In general [the mean of $T$ does not exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646428/mean-and-variance-of-reciprocal-normal-distribution). You can determine the density of $T$ analytically via its cumulative distribution function. For example in the simple case $\mu=S$ and $\sigma=b=1$ you can compute the cdf of $1/Z$ as follows: If $u>0$ then
$$
\begin{align}
P\left(\frac1Z\le u\right)&=P\left(\frac1Z\le u, Z<0\right) + P\left(\frac1Z\le u, Z>0\right)\\
&=\frac12 +P\left(Z\ge \frac1u\right)\\
&=\frac12 +\int_{1/u}^\infty \phi(z)\,dz,
\end{align}
$$
where $\phi$ denotes the standard normal density. You can differentiate this last expression using the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule to obtain
$$
f_{1/Z}(u) = \frac1{u^2}\phi\left(\frac1u\right).
$$ The case $u<0$ is handled similarly. The density in this simple case is bimodal.

Comment: Thanks. So there is no trivial solution to deriving simple statistics out of it. If T>0 then there is some simplification. In my study case I look for a confidence interval for $T$, in the case where $y = tX + c$, with $c$ normally distributed, thus the distribution of $T$ is actually the ratio of two Gaussians. This [paper](http://www.yaroslavvb.com/papers/marsaglia-ratios-of-normals.pdf) covers the derivation of this distribution in the general case, not covering how to get statistics from it in special cases.